# InsertMenuItem cutting off the string to first char

Tags: c#, menu

I am trying to modify window's system menu using InsertMenuItem (instead of InsertMenu - the reason is that I want to insert submenus eventually). Language is C#.

Tried inserting a new item, tried getting existing item and reinserting it, it inserts, but the item string is shown in the menu only as the first character. Anyone have a clue about what I am missing?

```
        // try creating one from scratch
        MENUITEMINFO it = new MENUITEMINFO();
        it.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(it);
        it.fMask = 64;// MIIM_STRING
        it.wID = 12345;
        it.dwTypeData = "Now is the time";
        it.fType = 0;
        it.cch = 0;
        InsertMenuItem(hSysMenu, 7, true, ref it);

        //try copying one
        GetMenuItemInfo(hSysMenu, (uint)0, true, ref it);
        it.cch += 10;
        it.dwTypeData = new string(' ', (int)(menuItemInfo.cch+10));
        GetMenuItemInfo(hSysMenu, (uint)0, true, ref it);
        it.wID = 123456;
        var err = InsertMenuItem(hSysMenu, 1, true, ref it);
```

The result of the above code
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally figured it out. I will leave this here so maybe someone else later will find it when they are baffled by this.

The reason was that the InsertMenuItem p/invoke was defined with

[DllImport("user32.dll")]  in the pinvoke.net site - see https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/insertmenu.html?diff=y

and it needs to be

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto) ]

I changed the pinvoke.net page to reflect it.